# Permissions Denied using BackupPC

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, file-permissions

I just set up BackupPC on an ubuntu 20.04 server host and it looks like I got everything working (almost), but I am getting a permission denied error when I initiate a backup, and I was hoping I could get some help. The permission Denied is when Apache tries writing to a directory specified in the application config. I believe apache is running as that user, so I am unsure why it is failing.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

BackupPC 4.3.2
```

Apache is running under the backuppc user (I believe).

```
root        1861  0.0  0.2  13992  8708 ?        Ss   10:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
backuppc    1865  0.0  0.1  13944  6564 ?        S    10:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
backuppc    1866  0.0  0.2 1939964 8216 ?        Sl   10:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
backuppc    1867  0.0  0.3 2005588 11980 ?       Sl   10:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

System Info for BackupPC Apache Process:

```
 backuppc.service - BackupPC server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/backuppc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-23 10:45:14 MDT; 58min ago
   Main PID: 1674 (BackupPC)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4203)
     CGroup: /system.slice/backuppc.service
             └─1674 /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/BackupPC/bin/BackupPC
```

The permissions of the directory I am trying to write to are:

```
/data/BackupPC

drwxrwxr-x  5 backuppc backuppc 4.0K May 23 09:52 BackupPC
```

The error in the backuppc log:

```
2021-05-23 11:00:01 mala-backup: mkdir /data/BackupPC: Permission denied at /usr/local/BackupPC/bin/BackupPC_dump line 245.
2021-05-23 11:16:12 User backupuser requested backup of mala-backup (mala-backup)
```

I have tried resetting the permissions on the directories, but they look appropriately set, and a change didn’t make a difference. I checked, and the backuppc user is in the backuppc group as well.

I appreciate if anyone has some ideas on how to resolve this!

Thank You!

Comment: What are the ownership permissions on /data and can you confirm that apparmor (and selinux) are not running. Morr kmportantly though you appear to have a user backuppc and backupuser - you probably need to resolve that.

Comment: That was it. The permissions on Data were incorrect. I kept looking, but I was looking at the directory behind /Data.